# How to Validate Canadian postal Code in Java? Checking for 2 types of input? ex: accepting A1A1A1 and A1A 1A1

Tags: java, string

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to input 2 different formats for a postal code (A1A1A1 or A1A  1A1) and I cannot for the life of me get it to work :/
My thought process was identifying both formats first and then using an if statement to check for the identified formats and then decide if its valid or not.
But I keep getting invalid when I try to enter the format with space in them (A1A 1A1).
so far I have this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidatingPostcodes {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a Postcode:");
    String Pc1 = "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]";
    String Pc2 = "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][ ][0-9][A-Z][0-9]";
        while (sc.hasNext())
        { if (sc.hasNext (Pc1))
            System.out.println ("Valid Postal Code");
            else if (sc.hasNext (Pc2))
            System.out.println ("Valid Postal Code");
            else System.out.println("Invalid Postal Code");
            sc.next();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could use `\s*` for zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Hint: your question has **nothing** to do with arrays or arraylist - so please dont use tags that dont apply to your question!

Comment: where? in string Pc2? I tried it there and it did not work T_T

Comment: Please keep in mind that I am a beginner programmer, been programming for like 3 months T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is: simply treat the two kinds of input **the same way** when processing them internally. Meaning:

1. Create **one** method that validates a 6-char potential ZIP code
2. But before calling that method, you check if your input contains a space as 4th character, and if so, you simply remove that space before giving it as parameter to your validation method.

But keep in mind: you probably want to keep the original string around - if you intend to give back "A1A A2A" later on. Of course, if you decide that users can enter ZIPs in two ways, but that they should get back "unified" format later on, then you can make that "space-dropping" thing permanent.

EDIT: you create a method

```
public boolean isValid(String zipCode) {
   that returns TRUE for valid zipcodes that have 6 (SIX!) chars and no spaces
```

and another method

```
public String normalizeZipCode(String incoming) {
   return incoming.replaceAll("\\s+","");
}
```

To be used like:

```
String zip1 = "A1A 1A1";
String zip2 = "A1A1A1";

String normalizedZip1 = normalizeZipCode(zip1);
String normalizedZip2 = normalizeZipCode(zip2);

System.out.println(isValid(normalizedZip1));
System.out.println(isValid(normalizedZip2));
```

The simple idea: if one format contains spaces, then just remove those spaces prior validation. In other words: you allow the user to **enter** data in **two** formats; but internally, you make sure that any usage of the second format is simply avoided, by turning it into the format that comes without spaces.

Comment: you mean have only Pc1 and work off of it?I don't get it :/ Can you show me an example if you have the time please?

Comment: Thank you for your help :3 I tried this method and it worked, only thing I am worried about is this method was not covered in class lol and so the prof is bound to take some marks off because I did not use "the method shown in class" lol

Comment: His answer is probably going to be a lot simpler than this since we have not covered creating and linking methods xD  But thanks a lot non the less I learned a lot from this <3